# Redirect all Wordpress url's to landing page except login url

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have gone through all the somewhat similar questions here, and tried out some apache cheat sheet rules I have bookmarked but no luck. In a nutshell I have a wordpress site with pages, posts, categories and tags all part of my xml sitemap. I would like to redirect everything to the home page except the login url for wordpress (example.com/wp-login.php) as I need to get back in.

I am putting up a landing page on this url while I work on a rebrand, and would like to 301 everything to the landing page. I guess I could take every url in my sitemap and put them in a redirect plugin but I am looking for a more direct htaccess solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.htaccess` with the code below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewriteRule ^/index\\.php$ http://www.yoursite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Hope it help.

Comment: That did not work, I received 404 errors on all the pages besides the home page. I did remove the www. from the rewriteRule as the non-www version is the canonical url.